# AWS S3 integration yields undefined method `match'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm working on a simple project using Paperclip to upload images.  Everything has been working just fine until I attempted to integrate S3 with Paperclip.  Upon 'uploading' a user's image I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'match' for nil:NilClass):` error. This only happens when I have my S3 configuration running - if I comment it out the file uploads perfectly.

My configuration:

```
development.rb:
....
....
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET_ID'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

My Model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_attached_file :image_file, default_url: "/myapp/images/:style/missing.png"
        validates_attachment_file_name :image_file, matches: [/png\Z/, /jpeg\Z/, /tiff\Z/, /bmp\Z/, /jpg\Z/]
```

entire error output from console:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/images_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/images_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

Things I tried:

- I added the AWS keys and bucket name directly into the code instead
  of as an environmental variable.
- As mentioned above, I commented out the AWS configuration in my environment file and it seemed to work perfectly.

It's probably worth mentioning that I installed the `fog` gem earlier to start configuring for Google Cloud Storage, but decided to stick with S3 instead.  I used `gem uninstall fog` to remove the gem but it appears some dependencies stayed behind.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Did you find a fix yet?

Comment: Did you try adding :s3_region => 'us-east-1' (or whatever the region your s3 is in) Here's a link which may help: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/95acf3b898bd782f4429d42fd2d8812505390328/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb#L96

Comment: Yes, I found that once I added my AWS region, it seemed to work just fine.  As an answer below mentioned, this isn't really thoroughly explained in the docs - and was even more confusing since I'd basically copy pasted code from another project that had worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add `:s3_region` to your config map:

E.g.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET_ID'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  },
  :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION']
}
```

Unfortunately this is a v5.0.0 feature (in Beta). And therefore there's nothing about it in the docs. However there is [a comment about it in the actual 5.0 code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/95acf3b898bd782f4429d42fd2d8812505390328/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb#L96).

Also good to note that the `s3_permissions` key in papertrail expects a string value now (it used to accept symbols).

```
:s3_permissions => 'public-read'
```

Comment: Now that v5 has been released officially, this has been documented in their [UPGRADING](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/4ef27eb84fe283f5dbe62fd99d7359822e79db28/UPGRADING#L10) doc.

Comment: For info, the `:region` value is in your file pass. ex : `EU (Frankfurt)` is `eu-central-1`

Comment: AWS Regions and Endpoints
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the region in you `s3_credentials`, in a way such as `region: ENV["AWS_REGION"]`.
As for cleaning up unused gems you can run `bundle clean`.

Comment: Did you restart your application after adding `:s3_region` in `development.rb`?